# Impact of Interpolation Types in Image Filtering (Laplacian Pyramids)

Tags: image-processing, interpolation, multi-scale-analysis

I am trying to construct Laplacian pyramids with different interpolation schemes such as bilinear, nearest neighbor, cubic and spline to observe the effect of interpolation types. I wrote a code in MATLAB to see the effect, but I could not come up with a solid answer that points the advantages and disadvantages of those schemes. I am trying to understand their advantages/disadvantages intuitively and mathematically,any help would be appreciated. Results that I have obtained are depicted in the following figures.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I found the solution in the following address: http://tanbakuchi.com/posts/comparison-of-openv-interpolation-algorithms/

Comment: It is better you display your solution.

Comment: Link is archived in https://web.archive.org/web/20190523112610/http://tanbakuchi.com/posts/comparison-of-openv-interpolation-algorithms/.